# aws eks upgrade from 1.23 to 1.24 version

Tags: amazon-eks

I plan to upgrade aws eks 1.23 to 1.24 version , is there any code changes needed  when build docker images and run it on 1.24 since no dockerd in 1.24 version and containerd replace it ?
Thanks in advance